# Swift: Accessing current navigation controller from a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell class "*ProductCell*"; I am trying to access the current navigation controller in order to update a barbuttonicon. I have tried the following code as this is what I use in my other UIViewControllers:

```
    let nav = self.navigationController as! MFNavigationController
    nav.updateCartBadgeValue()
```

However it states that the

> value of type ProductCell has no member navigationController

I am aware that this is not a `UIViewController` but surely you should be able to access the current navigation controller the same way?

I also know that you can access the navigation controller by using `UIApplication` in the following way:

```
let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
```

I am not sure if that is a good way of doing it though.

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question.  It's not pretty, but it has always worked.

Comment: Think about the design principles behind collection views and collection view cells. The cells are typically just inanimate things (static reflections of some part of your data model) that needn't know about other kinds of state or application logic. In MVC patterns (which I think is dodgy, but it works fairly well) the controller -- i.e. the collection view controller -- should be handling that.

Comment: You are doing things wrong when you need to access a controller from a view. Revise your approach to configure the cell from a controller (the UICollectionView's controller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a property to you cell class that weakly references a UINavigationController

```
weak var navigationController: UINavigationController?
```

you will need to assign it in your cellForRow(atIndexPath:_) method.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourReuseID") as! YourCellClass
cell.navigationController = navigationController //will assign your viewController's navigation controller to the cell

return cell
```

Answer (score 5):

`UIResponder` chain will help here.

You can search the responder chain to find the controller for any view

```
extension UIView {

    func controller() -> UIViewController? {
        if let nextViewControllerResponder = next as? UIViewController {
            return nextViewControllerResponder
        }
        else if let nextViewResponder = next as? UIView {
            return nextViewResponder.controller()
        }
        else  {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func navigationController() -> UINavigationController? {
        if let controller = controller() {
            return controller.navigationController
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

`controller()` will return the closest responder that is of type `UIViewController`
Then on the returned controller you just need to find its navigation controller. You can use `navigationController()` here.

Answer (score 0):

Unless things change, this is a good way to do it.  To give you an example of a messier solution... You could add a

```
let hostViewController:UIViewController
```

property to your cell and add an initializer to handle it

```
let cell = ProductCell(vc: self)
```

But I don't think that's a better way to do it. your suggestion works fine.

```
let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
```